# Cómo resolver este problema con un bucle?

Tags: java, netbeans

Lo que me sucede es que el programa corre bien y todo,pero a la hora de darme el dato final no lo muestra en consola,y no se que pueda ser, porque creo que las variables estan bien,los codigos igual y no se si me falta algo mas,agradesco nuevamente sus ayudas...aqui les dejo mis codigos

```
 int numero,contador = 0;

numero = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite un numero: "));

   
while   (numero >= 0)    {
  if (numero >= 0){
      contador++;
   numero = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite otro numero: "));
   
   }
  
  else {
       System.out.println("Usted ha introducido: "+contador+"numeros");
       break;
       }
    }     
}
```

}

Comment: Si la variable `numero` es negativa nunca entrará en el bloque `while` y, por tanto, tampoco en el `else`, porque este cumple la misma condición...

Comment: muchas gracias,entiendo lo que me dices,y me imagine que el error estuviera en esa parte,pero como estoy empezando creo que es normal que tenga errores como esos,ya vere como lo arreglo,agradecido por su atencion...

Comment: Te comento, el if dentro del while no es necesario porque ya el while funciona como tal al evaluar numero >= 0. De esta forma, sólo te quedarían las instrucciones if y tendrías que cambiar el else por un if o sacarlo del while y hacer lo mismo

Comment: que es lo que debe realizar tu codigo?? si es contar la cantidad de numeros positivos ingresados hasta ingresar un numero negativo quiza debes hacer uso de un doWhile

Comment: si estaba pensando en usa un do while,el programa lo que debe hacer es que cuando se entre un numero negativo,el pare y diga la cantidad de numeros que se han introducido..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ten presente que el bucle [while](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_while_loop.asp) evalúa la condicional antes de aplicar el ciclo repetitivo

si vos ingresas un numero positivo ingresaras al ciclo y caerá en la primera condicional `if` la cual te pide otro numero obviando `else` si seguís ingresando números positivos seguirá aplicándose lo mismo, pero que pasa si ingresas un negativo al ingresarlo estarás en el `if` obviando `else` y al evaluar la condicional nuevamente en el `while` tendrás un negativo por lo cual no entrara en el bucle ,es por ello que no te imprime el mensaje esperado

Recomendación Usar un bucle [`do while`](https://www.w3schools.in/java/loops/do-while) el cual ejecuta y después evalúa

```
do{
   numero = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite otro numero: "));
   
   if(numero >= 0){
      contador++;
   }
  
  else {
       System.out.println("Usted ha introducido: "+contador+" numeros");
       break;
       }

}while(numero >= 0);
```